# Duplicate parent and child data in jpql (JPA)

Tags: java, jpa, jax-rs, jpql

I have a Production class and ProductionDetail  entity class where Id of Production table is a foreignKey as production_id in ProductionDetail entity class so my both entity class with mapping has given bellow

Production Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_production")
@XmlRootElement

public class TblProduction implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "PRODUCTION_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date productionDate;

    @Column(name = "START_DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date startDatetime;

    @Column(name = "END_DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date endDatetime;

    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "MACHINE_UUID")
    private String machineUuid;

    **Relation with Production Details Table**
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "production")
    @XmlElement(name = "productionDetails")
    private List<TblProductionDetail> productionDetailList;


    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "MACHINE_UUID", referencedColumnName = "UUID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private MstMachine mstMachine;

    @XmlTransient
    public MstMachine getMstMachine() {
       return this.mstMachine;
   }
}
```

Production Details Entity Class:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "tbl_production_detail")
    @XmlRootElement
    public class TblProductionDetail implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private String id;
        @Size(max = 45)
        @Column(name = "COMPONENT_ID")
        private String componentId;
        @Size(max = 45)
        @Column(name = "PRODUCTION_ID")
        private String productionId;

        **Relation with Production Class** 
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCTION_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, 
                    updatable = false)
        private TblProduction production;

        @Transient
        public String componentCode;
        @Transient
        public String componentName;


        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "COMPONENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")  
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private MstComponent mstComponent;

        @XmlTransient
        public MstComponent getMstComponent() {
            return this.mstComponent;
        }
        public void setMstComponent(MstComponent mstComponent) {
            this.mstComponent = mstComponent;
        }
    }
```

ParentList Class:

```
  public class TblProductionList {
      private List<TblProduction> productionList;   
      public TblProductionList() {
            productionList = new ArrayList<>();
      }
      public List<TblProduction> getTblProductions() {
            return productionList;
      }
      public void setTblProductions(List<TblProduction> tblProductionList) {
            this.productionList = tblProductionList;
      }
  }
```

BusinessLogic(DAO Class):

```
       public TblProductionList getJson() {
            TblProductionList response = new TblProductionList();
            StringBuilder retrieveQuery = new StringBuilder();

            retrieveQuery.append(" SELECT prod FROM TblProduction prod ");
            retrieveQuery.append(" JOIN FETCH prod.productionDetailList ");
            retrieveQuery.append(" WHERE prod.endDatetime IS NULL ");
            retrieveQuery.append(" AND prod.machineUuid IS NOT NULL ");
            retrieveQuery.append(" AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT tpt FROM 
            TblProductionThset tpt WHERE prod.id = tpt.productionId) ");
            retrieveQuery.append(" AND EXISTS (SELECT mmfd FROM 
            MstMachineFileDef mmfd WHERE prod.machineUuid = mmfd.machineUuid 
            AND mmfd.hasThreshold = 1) ");
            retrieveQuery.append(" ORDER BY prod.id ");
            Query query = 
            entityManager.createQuery(retrieveQuery.toString());
            List thresholdList = query.getResultList();       
            response.setTblProductions(thresholdList);

            return response;
        }
```

According to the database I am getting expected master child data like below
[image]

After designing this entity class I am expecting that I will get  3 master records where each record has 2 detail records. But I am getting 6  duplicate master records with 12 child records. Can anyone suggest to me please where is my code became wrong and why this situation raised?  please check the JSON data that I am getting from API.

[image]

Comment: Can we see your DAO code please, as the entities look ok to me.

Comment: I added please check the DAO code.

Answer (score 0):

> > change your array list to hash set then records are not duplicate.

Comment: HashSet applied but the same result found. Don't suggest any answer on the fly my second question is WHY? That means kindly you should explain the reason.